# How to use a placeholder within an if statement to access a property

Tags: c#, json, discord.net

I don't want to use lots of if statements to determine which property needs to be accessed and instead wondered if something like a placeholder could be used.

I attempted to code something with placeholders and this is where I encounted my problem.

```c#
if (rootObject.permissions.{commandGroup}.{commandName})
{
    //do something                
}
```

This would allow the property accessed to change based on the value of the string in commandGroup and commandName without having to use several if statements for when the JSON gets expanded.

Here is the problem if statement:

```c#
//Command is an instance of CommandInfo from Discord.Net
string commandGroup = command.Module.Group;
string commandName = command.Name;


if (rootObject.permissions.commandGroup.commandName)
{
    //do something
}
```

Here is how the JSON file is being stored in a class:

```c#
    internal class RootObject
    {
        public Permissions permissions { get; set; }
        public int points { get; set; }
    }
    internal class Permissions
    {
        public Response response { get; set; }
    }
    internal class Response
    {
        public bool ping { get; set; }
        public bool helloWorld { get; set; }
    }
```

For example, if the commandGroup was Response and the commandName was ping, how would I use an if statement to determine if the value stored in rootObject.permissions.response.ping.

Comment: you could check the type of commandGroup, and act on that. Ex `if(commandGroup.GetType() == typeof(Response))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it using reflection, like this:

```
public static class PermissionsExtensions {
    public static T CommandGroup<T>(this Permissions permissions, string commandGroup)
    {
         PropertyInfo commandGroupProperty = typeof(Permissions).GetProperty(commandGroup);
         return (T)(commandGroupProperty.GetValue( permissions));
    }
    public static bool CommandProperty<T>(this T commandGroup, string commandProperty) 
    {
        PropertyInfo commandPropertyProperty = typeof(T).GetProperty( commandProperty);
        return (bool)(commandPropertyProperty.GetValue( commandGroup));
    }
}
```

Then you would use it like so:

```
bool result = rootObject.permissions.CommandGroup<Response>( "response").CommandProperty( "ping");
```

Tip: use capitalized names for properties in classes, and lower-case names for parameters.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the properties you want to access are all `bool`. You can store all of them in a `Dictionary<string, bool>`:

```
internal class RootObject
{
    public Dictionary<string, bool> permissions { get; set; } = new Dictionary<string, bool> {
        { "response.ping", false },
        { "response.helloworld", false },
        // add more here...
    };
    public int points { get; set; }
}
```

Now you you can access the dictionary like this:

```
if (rootObject.permissions[$"{commandGroup}.{commandName}"])
```